# Computer running on grub console

Tags: 12.04, grub2, 13.10

I just restared my computer and the graphic ubuntu grub no longer appears. Now there's a console with the grub prompt. I have no idea what to do and I can't even start any OS because I don't know how, I just want to get back to the way it used to be.

I think this happened because I made and update, then I was asked if I wanted grub to be restored to default and I just said yes. I didn't expect this to happen.

I am not very skilled with Linux as you can see... what can I do?

Comment: try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to have to be a bit more specific about what the "console" looks like. There are several GRUB consoles I'm afraid. I picture would really help :)

Comment: It's a black background console with a grub> prompt and it says press TAB to display the commands, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot from live CD/USB and use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)